# Intellisense for C# Not Working For Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, intellisense, visual-studio-code, project.json

I am using OSX and when I first create the project using dotnet Intellisense works fine, it's when I close the application is when it never works again with the same message coming up:

[image: I have the C# extension installed and becuase it works after being created i'm sure i have all the correct tools]

When I open up the output this is what it shows:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Dumb question: are you running the latest version?

Comment: have you installed the C# extension?

Comment: @RobPethi Yeah i have it installed. I even updated it yesterday.

Comment: Shouldn't you figure out the "Some projects are having trouble loading" before looking at "intellisense isn't working"? Maybe intellisense isn't working because the project is corrupted. Anyways, on my Windows system sometimes intellisense just stops working and I have to use the [shortcuts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx) where I put the text cursor by the thing I wanted "intellisensed" and hit `ctrl+space`.

Comment: @Quantic Intellisense is the only part of the program not working. I can still debug and run the code. I have also tried on multiple projects and they all yield the same result of working at first then after closing VS Code it never works again

Comment: Reading your screenshot it appears to be related to OmniSharp. [This issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/375) looks roughly identical.